# I over stayed in the US for 6 years back in the 70s. Can I return with a tourist visa after 35 years?

Tags: visas, usa

I went through a deportation hearing and eventually I married an US citizen and got a green card. But after two years we split. I returned to my home country and have stayed here for more than 30 years. Because of work reasons, I had to apply years later for a visa because my flight to Europe had to pass through NY. I got a visa for 10 years. Using that visa I made another trip to San Francisco and stayed there just a few days. Never had a problem. Those trips were in 1998 and 2004. This year I want to apply for a tourist visa to visit friends in the US. Will I get it? Do they keep records for more than 30 years?

Comment: Given that you had a visa after your overstay I am not exactly sure what your question is?

Comment: Why would you be refused a visa now, when you got one before?

Comment: Because they might search and find that indeed I violated the law once. I still don't know how I got a new visa years after (in 1998). Perhaps because in 1998 it did not exist today tight security measures..

Comment: Did you tell the truth in 1998? If you lied to them and they find out about the lie then that is a much bigger black mark than an overstay many years ago.

Answer (score 10):

Whether you will receive a visa depends on the ties you can show to your home country, the documents you provide, and the answers you give at your interview. None of us are the Consular Officer reviewing your application. Therefore, none of us can really answer this question. You'll have to apply.

You received a 10 year multiple entry visa before and didn't overstay, so that's a big point in your favor. It seems unlikely they would count your previous overstay against you now when they were ok with it back in 1998.

Your visa application form will ask about your previous travel to the US. You should answer those questions honestly and accurately, as your chances of receiving a visa will drop dramatically if they find you have lied to them.

That said, the decision whether to issue a visa is a case-by-case judgement and will depend on your entire application and personal circumstances.

Comment: Agree with this!